# Ruby Collection Reference

Tags: ruby, arrays, collections, reference

I'm wondering what the difference is between a normal variable and a collection. Here's an example for a normal variable.

```
a = "something"
b = a
a = "else"
p b # => "something"
```

As far as I know, `b` holds a reference to the same object as `a`, the string (object) `"something"`. Therefore its value changes when `a` changes. Or to be more specific, when the referenced object changes. Why is this behavior different from the following array example?

```
string = "hello"
array = [string]
p array # => ["hello"]

string = "something else"
p array # => ["hello"]
```

Close as I can figure the array doesn't hold the variable `a`, but takes over the reference from `a` and dumps the variable holding the reference (`a`). So when `a` is changed, it has no impact on the array, as it has no underlying variable being changed.

Is this how this works?

**Update**
To be more clear of what I mean:

```
a = 'hello'
array = [a]
p a.object_id # 2168500580
p array[0].object_id # 2168500580
```

Ok, this means that the pointers `a` and `array[0]` point to the same object in memory. What I thought is that the pointer `array[0]` IS the pointer `a`, like literally the same, not a copy or something else. So when I change a, it gets changed everywhere. Like when I write `a.upcase!`. But when I just write `a.upcase!`, it's like `a` and `array[0]` aren't the same pointers anymore.

Comment: This is very simple. If the first example is clear to you, that will answer the second confusion you have now. :-)

Comment: In your first example `p b` will print `"something"` not `"else"`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but closevoted. What is written cannot be reproduced. At the end of the first chunk of the code, `b` returns `"something"`.

Comment: Thanks Uri Agassi and @sawa oh man yeah you're right, sorry about that, I just corrected it. The question was written on a phone while on the train, guess it's not perfect to write such questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a`, `b`, `string` and `array` in your example all hold *references* to objects. When you assign a new value to any of those, it does not change the objects they are referencing, but rather the reference.

Example:

```
a = "something"
b = a
```

Now `a` and `b` are *looking at the same thing*. After doing this though:

```
a = "else"
```

`a` is no longer looking at `"something"`. We did no change `"something"`, only told `a` to look at `"else"`. For that reason - nothing really happened to `b` - it still looks at `"something"`, so:

```
p b # "something"
```

Same thing happens with the `array` example. The `array`'s first element looks at the same thing `string` looks at, until you change what `string` looks at - it doesn't change the array, or the value of the element it looks at - it simply *changes what `string` looks at*.

---

To replicate what you *think* should happen, the object itself must change.

In ruby (contrary to other popular languages) `String` is *not* immutable, so we can demonstrate it:

```
a = "something"
b = a

p b # "something"
a.upcase!
p b # "SOMETHING"
```

And:

```
string = "hello"
array = [string]
p array # => ["hello"]

string.upcase!
p array # => ["HELLO"]
```

In these examples, we did not assign anything new to `a` and `string`, but rather changed the state of the object they are currently assigned to, and all references looking at that object also see the change.

Comment: Surely you mean that strings are mutable, since you clearly demonstrate that a string can be mutated.

Comment: @FrederickCheung - damn double-negatives :P, fixed, thanks

Comment: @UriAgassi so is it correct than, that `the array doesn't hold the variable a, but takes over the reference from a`? Because if I change what `a` looks at, `array[a]` should change as well because `a == array[a]`, right? I mean `a` and `array[a]` are literally the same. Or is it more like `array[a] = a` is analogously to `array[b] = a` because in both cases it's not the same variable?

Comment: @LinusAn - No. you can check this in `irb` - `a != array[a]`. The array holds a _copy of the reference_ of `string`, much like `b` holds a copy of the reference of `a`. When you re-assign `a` or `string`, `b` and `array` (respectively) don't care, since they hold their own copy to the reference (which did not change).

Comment: @UriAgassi that's the answer I was looking for which explains everything. Thank you so much!